# Weird... Angular Proxy not working properly

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

Im working on an ***Angular*** / ***Laravel*** project , but I’m facing troubles configuring the Grunt proxy properly, I've followed several tutorials and made some research in order to solve this issue , but I haven’t Succeded.

The problem is that the configured Proxy  is not redirecting to the host as it should be, I setted to forward request from `/localhost:9000/api` to `/localhost:8000/api` , but when I make a request :

Referer URL : `http://localhost:9000/api/whataver`
Request URL : `http://localhost:9000/api/whatever`

Is making a request to the same host, so the requests are not be proxy correctly, any suggestions?

Here's part of my grunt file:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  proxies: [
      {
          context: '/api',
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: 8000,
          https: false,
          changeOrigin: false
      }
  ],
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: [
       '.tmp',
       '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      ],
      middleware: function (connect,options) {

        var middlewares = [];
        
        if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
          options.base = [options.base];
        }

        // Set up the proxy
        middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest);

        //server static files
        middlewares.push(
          modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
             connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        );
        return middlewares;
      }
    }
  }
```

I'd appreciate any help, Thank you!

Comment: Hey Hector, I'm facing the exact same issue here, were you ever able to find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Hello danboh, yes I found a solution... Let me know the way you're doing it and maybe I'd be able to help you... However I'm gonna post the solution I found with my actual configuration.

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I asked this question.  I found the solution back then, but I never posted my solution, so here it goes:

In the first place there was nothing wrong with the configuration, everything was OK in both my Laravel and Angular. Apparently the problem was a bug  with the Laravel proxy :

When you serve your Laravel app with the artisan command :

```
php artisan serve
```

By default it serves in **localhost:8000**, that is not wrong

When you serve your Angular app with the grunt:

```
grunt serve
```

By default it serves in **localhost:9000**, Its Okay too, but by being both server using the logical **localhost**, then this's causing some bug in the Laravel app.

It can be solve as easy as serving in the same localhost but in other words, literally. here is the solution:

```
php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1
```

And that was it, the bug has to be gone by now.

**note**: This solution just applies for the local environment I don't know how it would behave in production.

Answer (score 0):

This answer should help

[AngularJS with Grunt - Connect to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858205/angularjs-with-grunt-connect-to-another-server)

Check your code with the steps mentioned in answer strictly.
You will get it.